# XPATH for href link isnt working. Getting invalid selector: It should be an element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate couple of Selenium scenarios from [this](http://ecommerce.saipratap.net/) website

i was trying to click on the "categories" link by giving the below XPATH

```
//a[contains(text(), 'CATEGORIES')]/@href
```

I am getting `InvalidSelector` error. Could you please suggest an alternative XPATH for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just for your reference:**

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="catlist.php">CATEGORIES</a></li>
  <li><a href="brands.php">BRANDS</a></li>
  <li><a href="products.php">PRODUCTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="cart.php">MY CART</a></li>
  <li><a href="tracking.php">TRACKING</a></li>
  <li><a href="customerlogin.php">ACCOUNT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="faq.php">FAQ'S</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Alternative way by using linktext:**
=> By.linkText("CATEGORIES")

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("CATEGORIES")).click();
```

Comment: ,linkText("") is not always works.This case it might work.

Comment: @kajal kundu: Does this always work By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'CATEGORIES')]")) ??

Answer (score 1):

"CATEGORIES" section on the page that you are trying to automate is stored as a text in the html structure, so you can find it using the below xpath which finds it by matching its text:

```
WebElement categoriesSection = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='CATEGORIES']"));
```

Comment: why did you change your answer?

Comment: Because there were two categories on the page and first i wrote the xpath for the other categories, then i found that the OP is asking for the categories with the anchor tag, so I edited my xpath.

Comment: First read the question what OP looking for.Just to give the answer is not a best practice.

Comment: OP has mentioned categories and if you check the webpage there are two categories on the page so i got confused and thats why i changed my xpath afterwards and if you see the edit history, the logic i have used is the same for both. However yes i will try that it wont happen in the future.

Comment: I have checked.The other element is a text field now tell me how do you click a text field.OP mentioned wants to click on anchor not text field.Thats why I said read first.

Comment: @KajalKundu Yes sure, this wont happen again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use action class to click on the element.

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'CATEGORIES')]"))).click().build().perform();
```

Please note: use following import.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Comment: There is a problem with this answer: when the node-set from `text()` node test is passed as argument for `contains` function, it will be casted by the `string` function. In short, you would be only testing the first text node.
The proper expression should be `//a[contains(.,'CATEGORIES')]`

Comment: @Alejandro: completely agree.